# Disable SSL Certificate Validation in Ballerina HTTP Client

Tags: ssl, ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake, ballerina-http

I need to call an endpoint with a self-signed certificate using the Ballerina HTTP client.

```
import ballerina/http;

http:Client httpClient = check new("<URL>");
```

Is there a way to disable SSL certificate validation in Ballerina?

Comment: Why? If you don't want it secure, why are you using SSL at all?

Comment: This is just for development environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling SSL certificate validation in the Ballerina `http:Client` can be achieved by configuring the secureSocket option in the client configuration.

```
import ballerina/http;

http:Client httpClient = check new("<URL>", {secureSocket: {enable: false}});
```

Reference: [Client SecureSocket Configuration](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/http/latest#ClientSecureSocket)